# When should delete be called on a gcnew allocated object?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I was reading the following [MSKB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311259) example and they perform a delete on a managed object.

I was under the impression you should never delete a garbaged collected object rather you must leave that to garbage collector.

What have I missed?

**Method 4**

```
 //#include <msclr/marshal.h>
 //using namespace msclr::interop;
 marshal_context ^ context = gcnew marshal_context();
 const char* str4 = context->marshal_as<const char*>(str);
 puts(str4);
 delete context;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`delete` in C++/CLI merely calls the [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) method on a managed object, if it implements the [`System::IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface – if it doesn't, it's effectively a noop. In fact, if you try to call the `Dispose` method on a managed object yourself, you'll get a compiler error – `delete` is the enforced idiom for disposing an object.

To be clear, it has nothing to do with memory management, noting of course that most finalizable objects will get GCed sooner if they're disposed.

Comment: So other then marking the object for more immediate GC there isn't really any good reason to use delete in the above example?

Comment: @Cube : No, fulfulling your end of the `IDisposable` contract is an excellent reason to **always** use `delete` whenever you're done with an object. Or better yet, use stack semantics for simulated RAII so you never have to use `delete`, and `Dispose` will automatically be called as soon as objects go out of scope.