# LevelDB asserts when deleting the LevelDB instance

Tags: c++, c++-cli, assert, assertions, leveldb

I get some super annoying asserts when I try to delete the leveldb instance and I'm not sure why it's happening!

The assert is happening in the [version_set.cc](http://leveldb.googlecode.com/svn-history/r28/trunk/db/version_set.cc) file:

```
void VersionSet::AppendVersion(Version* v) {
  // Make "v" current
  assert(v->refs_ == 0); // <---??? how do I avoid this assertion?
  // the rest of the source code is available in the link to version_set.cc
}
```

Additionally, it asserts in another place in the same file:

```
Version::~Version() {
  assert(refs_ == 0); // <-- Again... how do I avoid this one too?
  // the rest of the source code is available in the link to version_set.cc
}
```

Here is more background details on the usage in my system, I have a:

- class `ExtStorage` (Extended Storage) which has a `LevelDB::DB` instance.
- class `EextStorageDotNet`, which is the C++/CLI wrapper around the `ExtStorage`.
- class `AltStorage`, which holds a pointer to an ExtStorage class (passed through the constructor):
- class `AltStorageDotNet`, which is the C++/CLI wrapper around the `AltStorage`.

The alternate storage class looks like this:

```
class AltStorage{
    ExtStorage* instance;
public:
    AltStorage(ExtStorage* extStorage):instance(extStorage){}

    ~AltStorage(){
        delete instance;
        instance = NULL;
    }
};
```

The `ExtStorage` class looks like this:

```
class ExtStorage{
    leveldb::DB* mydb;
public:
    ExtStorage(/*some parameters*/){
         mydb = new leveldb::DB(/*parameters*/);
    }

    // Destructor
    ~ExtStorage() {
        Close();
    }

    // deletes the leveldb::DB instance
    void Close() {
        if(mydb == NULL) {
            delete mydb; // <-- Asserts every time I get here when using with the AltStorageDotNet
            mydb= NULL;

            // Close the L1 and L2 caches
            // only once (
        }
    }
}
```

The `AltStorageDotNet` class looks like this:

```
public ref class AltStorageDotNet{
    AltStorage* altInstance;
    ExtStorageDotNet^ extInstance;
public:
    AltStorageDotNet() {
        ExtStorage extStorage = new ExtStorage(/*params*/);
        altInstance = new AltStorage(extStorage);
        extInstance = gcnew ExtStorageDotNet(extStorage);
    }

    ~AltStorageDotNet(){
        delete altInstance;
        altInstance = NULL;
        // no need to delete extInstance since it was created with gcnew 
    }

    !AltStorageDotNet(){
        delete altInstance;
        altInstance = NULL;
        // no need to delete extInstance since it was created with gcnew
    }

    inline ExtStorageDotNet^ GetExtInstance(){return extInstance;}
};
```

The DotNet wrappers look like this:

```
public ref class ExtStorageDotNet{
private:
    ExtStorage* instance;
public:
    ExtStorageDotNet(ExtStorage* extStorage){
        instance = extStorage;
    }

    ~ExtStorageDotNet(){
        delete instance;
        instance = NULL;
    }

    !ExtStorageDotNet(){
        delete instance;
        instance = NULL;
    }

    void Close(){instance->Close();}
};
```

Whenever I use the `ExtStorageDotNet` wrapper in my C# application everything works good and there are no asserts. However, when I use the `AltStorageDotNet` wrapper and I access the `ExtStorageDotNet` wrapper, then I get the asserts when closing the database. **This is all part of a test suite in which I initialize an instance for each test case and close it after each test case; the associated database files get deleted before a new test case begins.** I don't see any reason why it should happen and the assertion is not helpful in tracking down the problem.

Comment: `// no need to delete extInstance since it was created with gcnew` this comment is **very** misguided.

Comment: I can't delete extInstance, there is no gcdelete... I can set it to null, but that's about it. "gcnew is for .NET reference objects; objects created with gcnew are automatically garbage-collected; it is important to use gcnew with CLR types" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202459/what-is-gcnew/202464#202464)

Comment: No, there is no `gcdelete`, but `delete` has entirely different semantics on managed types vs. unmanaged types. You still _should_ use it, and in some cases _need_ to -- this is likely one of those cases.

Comment: What about the automatic garbage collection?

Comment: Garbage collection is about memory management; `IDisposable` is about deterministic finalization -- for your purposes, these are completely orthogonal concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got rid of the nested references, but that didn't solve the problem. As it turns out, the issue causing this problem was not quite where I was looking at. The issue occurs when a user gets an iterator to the database and fails to delete the iterator prior to deleting the database. This was discussed in a [google group relating to level db](http://groups.google.com/group/leveldb/browse_thread/thread/234fe037cd9adef2).

```
// Caller should delete the iterator when it is no longer needed.
// The returned iterator should be deleted before this db is deleted.
virtual Iterator* NewIterator(const ReadOptions& options) = 0;
```

When the user gets the iterator they should delete it prior to deleting the db, otherwise they will get the assertion mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it's related to your asserts or not, but this code is guaranteed to cause memory corruption. Both `ExtStorageDotNet` and `AltStorageDotNet` are disposable and finalizable, and both (directly or indirectly) `delete` the instance of `ExtStorage` -- invariably, one will `delete` it after the other already has.

Also, as I said in my comment, the comment in your code saying `no need to delete extInstance since it was created with gcnew` is way off -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087480/when-should-delete-be-called-on-a-gcnew-allocated-object/7089409#7089409) for details. (I assume you know C# and thus about `IDisposable`; if you don't, then you really need to do some reading.)

Comment: OK, I don't see how I would get memory corruption if `delete` is equivalent to a nop on a NULL pointer (which is what I set the pointer to after I delete it). Furthermore, according to [the answer on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202459/what-is-gcnew/202464#202464), objects created with gcnew get garbage collected automatically.

Comment: @Lirik : You set `ExtStorageDotNet::instance` to `NULL`, but how do you expect that to affect `AltStorage::instance` (and vice-versa)? Also, forget about garbage collection for this discussion, as it's entirely irrelevant to `IDisposable`. ;-]

Comment: got it: don't need to delete the `AltStorage::instance`.

Comment: @Lirik : Not quite. :-/ You need to restructure your code so that only one object owns a given unmanaged object, _and_ you need to `delete` the managed objects you own in your destructors (but not your finalizers). Again, please do some reading about `IDisposable`; there are many articles about implementing it correctly on MSDN.

Comment: OK, I don't implement `IDisposable`, so how would deleting `AltStoragDotNet::extInstance` help me?

Comment: @Lirik : A "destructor" on a managed type _is_ an implementation of `IDisposable`; the destructor syntax is just syntactic sugar. Likewise, the `!Classname()` syntax is just syntactic sugar for overriding [`Object::Finalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx). Now it may be time to read up on some C++/CLI fundamentals. ;-]

Comment: And `!AltStorageDotNet` is the finalizer? So I can just get rid of the finalizer and that should take care of one of the problems.

Comment: @Lirik : No... When you own unmanaged memory/objects, you **always** need a finalizer. This should be covered in any article about implementing `IDisposable` correctly.

Comment: So where do I delete, in the finalizer or in the dispose/distructor?

Comment: @Lirik : `delete` unmanaged objects in both; `delete` managed objects in only the destructor. Again, this should be covered in any article about implementing `IDisposable` correctly (_hint_, _hint_ -- go read some).