# c++/cli best way to retrieve wpf window result

Tags: c#, wpf, c++-cli

I have a `WPF` window and I'm calling it from a `C++/cli` code and it works fine. What I need is what's the best way to intercept user action I mean whether he click `OK` or `Cancel`. Wath I think to do is to define a `Boolean` property in my window and set it depends on user action. Here is my code :

```
MyWindowView^ window = gcnew MyWindowView();
System::Windows::Interop::WindowInteropHelper^ windowInteropHelper = gcnew System::Windows::Interop::WindowInteropHelper(window);
windowInteropHelper->Owner = (IntPtr)AfxGetMainWnd()->m_hWnd;
window->WindowStartupLocation = System::Windows::WindowStartupLocation::CenterScreen;
window->ShowDialog();
if ()
{
    //some action
} 
else
{
    //
}
```

Also I want to know do I need to delete the `window` object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Window.ShowDialog` returns dialog [result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx). I can't see any reason to get this result in some way, that differs from C# or VB .NET:

```
System::Nullable<System::Boolean> result = window->ShowDialog();
if (result.HasValue)
{
    // OK or Cancel
    if (result.Value)
    {
        // OK clicked
    }
    else
    {
        // Cancel clicked
    }
}
else
{
    // dialog closed via system menu or Alt+F4
}
```

> do I need to delete the window object ?

No, you don't. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7089409/580053) answer.

Comment: Hi Dennis actually for the Ok and Cancel  buttons are custom not the defined ones for dialog result so do you think that ShowDialog can get the result of that buttons

Comment: @MoezRebai: what do you mean by "custom buttons"? Anyway, if your buttons will set `Window.DialogResult` property, you'll get a proper return value.